# When union type variable initialized any value, then if the value be initialized to every union element?

Tags: c

```
typedef union jkk
{
    int a;
    char b[10];
    float c;
} y;

int main(){
    y instance_of_y = {100};
}
```

In the following piece of program union y initialized y={100}
Then shall it be assigned to a ,b and c all the elements or only to the first one a.

Comment: This program would not work, since y is not a variable. It is a type.

Comment: Why shouldn't you try it yourself?

Comment: If you don't mind, I've fixed the question so it compiles. Upvoted, as I don't know the answer off hand.

Comment: An `union` only has **one** element at a time.

Comment: @Bathsheba: It is exactly like for a `struct`. You can use a designated initialiser (which is good advice in general).

Comment: @Olaf: For some reason I thought it was wildly different between C and C++. But yes, having thought about this a little more, it's rather obvious.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I don't see the C++ tag, so that language does not matter here.

Comment: It would have mattered if I had spouted a C++ answer ;-) I program in C very little these days, sadly.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Ah, just checked your profile. I thought you are more a C guy:-) Nevermind.

Comment: Nobody's perfect.

Answer (score 2):

When using `{100}`, the member `a` is *active* with the value of 100. This is because *brace initialisation* initialises the first `union` member.

You ought to regard the other members of the `union` as inactive and uninitialised.

Comment: Is there not an exception with member `unsigned char next_member[sizeof first_member_type];`?  `next_member[]` would be well initialized too?

Comment: Yes indeed there are exceptions - the unsigned char array portion that overlaps the first member being an important example, even if - I think - the first member contains padding bits. I flatter myself into thinking I was careful with the language in my answer, especially with respect to 'ought to'. I might frame the padding bits part into a question when I get home.

Comment: @Bathsheba "You ought to regard the other members of the union as inactive and uninitialised." is it really so ? I've done some tests with gcc and clang and all other members are always zeros. Can you give me some information how did you come to this conclusion ?

Comment: @Lazureus: The C standard talks about the "active member of a union".

Comment: @Bathsheba, thanks I'm going to search for it, can you also give me a hint where did you find the statements that rest of members is uninitialized ?

Comment: @Lazureus: They are not necessarily uninitialised which is why I'm careful enough to say "You ought to regard".

Comment: @Bathsheba, oh ok, so you're not 100% sure. Thanks anyway, when I'm going to find the answer I'm going to come back here.

Comment: @Lazureus: Also have a look around the critera for type punning through a union. Note that in C++, pretty much all bets off - the two languages differ in this respect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186548/discussion-between-lazureus-and-bathsheba).